# You attempted to set the key on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, state, android-mapview

In the following example:

- `MapView` displays elements of a `ListView` as **annotations**
- **Clicking** on a `ListView` element should result in painting it in **blue** color.
- Bonus if the `MapView` and `ListView` efficiently use the state object

Modifying the `DataSource` of `ListView` seems to cause the conflict when the `active` attribute gets modified:

> You attempted to set the key 'active' with the value 'false' on an
>   object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.

[image]

What is the right way of setting the state?

[RNPlay Example](https://rnplay.org/apps/_HWIOg)

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,View,ListView,MapView,Text,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

var annotations = [
        {
          title: 'A',active: false,latitude: 45,longitude: 26,latitudeDelta: 0.015,longitudeDelta: 0.015,
        },{
          title: 'B',active: false,latitude: 49,longitude: 14,latitudeDelta: 0.015,longitudeDelta: 0.015,
        },{
          title: 'C',active: false,latitude: 26,longitude: 25,latitudeDelta: 0.015,longitudeDelta: 0.015,
        }
      ]

class SampleApp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    });
    this.state = {
      region: annotations[0],
      annotations: annotations,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(annotations)
    };
  }

  handleClick(field) {
    if (this.previousField) {
      this.previousField.active = false;
    }
    this.previousField = field;
    field.active = true;
    this.setState({
      region: field,
    });
  }

  renderField(field) {
    let color = (field.active == true)?'blue':'yellow'; 

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick.bind(this,field)}>
        <Text style={{backgroundColor:color,borderWidth:1}}>{field.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',alignSelf:'stretch'}}>
        <MapView
            style={{flex:0.5,alignSelf:'stretch',borderWidth:1}}
          region={this.state.region}
          annotations={this.state.annotations}
        />
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(field) => this.renderField(field)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**The Problem**

When you set `field.active = true;` or `this.previousField.active = false;`, you're modifying an object (`field`) that is present in the datasource of your `ListView`.  The `ListView` throws the error because it freezes its datasource when you create it using `cloneWithRows`.  This is to ensure that the datasource can't be modified outside of the normal React component lifecycle (like `setState`).  Instead, `ListView.DataSource` objects are designed to be changed with `cloneWithRows`, which returns a *copy* of the existing datasource.

If you're familiar with the [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) library, it's very similar to the philosophy of having reducer functions return a *copy* of the state, rather than modifying the existing state.

**Cloning the DataSource**

To solve this problem, instead of mutating `field` objects in your `handleClick` function, what you really want to do is create a new data array with values already set (like `active`), and then call `setState` with a new datasource for your `ListView` created with `cloneWithRows`.  If you do this, you actually don't even need the `annotations` key in your state at all.

Code is probably more helpful than words here:

```
handleClick(field) {

  //iterate over annotations, and update them.
  //I'm taking 'title' as a unique id property for each annotation, 
  //for the sake of the example.
  const newAnnotations = annotations.map(a => {
    //make a copy of the annotation.  Otherwise you'll be modifying
    //an object that's in your listView's datasource,
    //and therefore frozen.
    let copyA = {...a};
    if (copyA.title === field.title) {
      copyA.active = true;
    } else {
      copyA.active = false;
    }
    return copyA;
  });

  this.setState({
    region: {...field, active: true},
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newAnnotations),
  });
}
```

I hope this helps!  Here's a code snippet containing the complete code you posted, with my modifications.  It's working for me just as you described it should on iOS using React Native 0.29.  You tagged the question android-mapview, so I'm assuming you're running Android, but the platform shouldn't really make a difference in this case.

```js
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,View,ListView,MapView,Text,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

var annotations = [
        {
          title: 'A',active: false,latitude: 45,longitude: 26,latitudeDelta: 0.015,longitudeDelta: 0.015,
        },{
          title: 'B',active: false,latitude: 49,longitude: 14,latitudeDelta: 0.015,longitudeDelta: 0.015,
        },{
          title: 'C',active: false,latitude: 26,longitude: 25,latitudeDelta: 0.015,longitudeDelta: 0.015,
        }
      ]

class SampleApp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    });
    this.state = {
      region: annotations[0],
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(annotations)
    };
  }

  handleClick(field) {

    //iterate over annotations, and update them.
    //I'm taking 'title' as a unique id property for each annotation, 
    //for the sake of the example.
    const newAnnotations = annotations.map(a => {
      //make a copy of the annotation.  Otherwise you'll be modifying
      //an object that's in your listView's datasource,
      //and therefore frozen.
      let copyA = {...a};
      if (copyA.title === field.title) {
        copyA.active = true;
      } else {
        copyA.active = false;
      }
      return copyA;
    });

    this.setState({
      region: {...field, active: true},
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newAnnotations),
    });
  }

  renderField(field) {
    console.log(field);
    let color = (field.active == true)?'blue':'yellow';

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick.bind(this,field)}>
        <Text style={{backgroundColor:color,borderWidth:1}}>{field.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',alignSelf:'stretch'}}>
        <MapView
          style={{flex:0.5,alignSelf:'stretch',borderWidth:1}}
          region={this.state.region}
          annotations={this.state.annotations}
        />
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(field) => this.renderField(field)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: It works with ios platform and your explanations did really help.

Comment: Great!  If it solves your problem, would you accept the answer?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Use spread operator for updating state or any immutable variable**

For eg my_state is my state variable:

```
 state = {
  my_state: {
    key1: value1,
  }
 }
```

**if you want to update this state use spread operator**

```
 let new_state = {...this.state.state_one};
 this.setState({my_state:new_state});
```