# Object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen in redux reducer in a react-native app

Tags: javascript, redux, react-native, spread-syntax

This is the first time I'm seeing this happen, I've been running the app for a while now and I've not changed the reducer so I'm not sure what's wrong.  I am creating a new state object using the spread op. and then assigning the value but getting the error listed.

CallStack:

- You attempted to set the key 'lastSeen' with the value ... on an Object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen
- Error stack is throwOnImmutableMutation (deepFreezeAndThrowOnMutationInDev.js:64:8)
- My file line number shown below

The line number it points me to is the assignment of lastSeen.

```
const initial = {
  ...
};

const BleCommunicator = (state = initial, action) => {
  let nextState = null;
  switch (action.type) {
  ...
  case c.DEVICE_DISCONNECTED:
    nextState = {
      ...state
    };
    nextState[action.device.id].lastSeen = moment(); //<-- this is where it is erroring
    delete nextState[action.device.id].rssi;
    nextState.connectedDevices = _.remove(nextState.connectedDevices, action.device.id);
    break;
...
return nextState;
}
```

EDIT: something that seems to be the cause is that I'm running an rx epic that is updating the values.  They take the normal path through actions/reducer but the second time the epic is run (on timer) it fails to update the value.  Is there something that could be happening under the hood that could cause me to be updating an old state?

EDIT2: This is only happening on Android. Here is a link to the object that is the state for the item being updated.  https://gist.github.com/anwarhamr/4c3ebc8e2a3d5166c025fd1cf69a7e1c

Comment: Is it possible that the action.device.id is null and this causes the error? Can you put a debugger above this line to see if any of the values for action and state is not right?

Comment: Nope the object at `nextState[action.device.id]` is there.

Comment: It doesn't consistently happen either. Every few times I run the app I get the RSOD pointing to this problem.

Comment: OK I found that this is only happening on android os

Comment: This link may be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270445/you-attempted-to-set-the-key-on-an-object-that-is-meant-to-be-immutable-and-has