# React native mobile app : getting Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-linking

I have created my first react native app for android and ios, I am currently focusing on Anroid only. Also I have created one react native sample library with some function.

Integrated this lib in sample app and try to run the same.
I am getting error as

```
E/ReactNativeJS: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
I/ReactNativeJS: 'Failed to print error: ', 'You attempted to set the key `file` with the value `undefined` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.'
E/ReactNativeJNI: Got JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded. (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2353)
E/ReactNativeJNI: Got JS Stack: isValidArgument@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2353:67
```

As I explain, this is just simple project with create command, I have just imported library from npm, and that is auto setup.

Check more log of error

```
unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call from JS
com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Maximum call stack size exceeded. (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2353)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Maximum call stack size exceeded. (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2353)
```

Can anyone help me here on this point, I am new in react native mobile app development. I am not able to resolve this issue.

Please help, Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You attempted to set the key on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270445/you-attempted-to-set-the-key-on-an-object-that-is-meant-to-be-immutable-and-has)

Comment: please post some more details about what you're doing in the app with some sample code and logcat of when error happens